# Retrieve thousands of record in ssrs Report deployed asp.net web applications

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, iis, reporting-services

I have a report deployed in asp.net web application, it works on small amount of data.

But when the data set contains thousands of records It may timeout on client side and data not appears.

So how can we solve this problem and retrieves unlimited amount of data to Client when query this report?

Comment: Why do you need thousands of records in the client? Can't you move some grouping to the server or move details to a sub-report?

Comment: increase your timeout length on both side on client side as well as server side

Comment: In Web.Config timeout execution is set to be 3600.. Is it the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Even without knowing the specifics of your situation, you should look into applying [paging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255278(v=sql.100).aspx) to your output report. On the server side, make sure that your query utilizes indexes applied to the source tables.